# Why forEach doesn't working for type changing of item of array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the type of each element of the array to numeric, but the string iterating over the array and transforming seems to be ignored and the original array remains the same.

```
arr.forEach(item => Number(item));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: (In other words you should add an example input to your question.)

Comment: I am also trying to use "parseInt" for item,but it's doesn't work too.

Comment: It seems you want to use `Array.prototype.map` function to convert each item into another type.

Comment: @DerekWang no, `Array.map()` freate a new array and doesn't change the arrays's items

Comment: arr = arr.map(item => Number(item)) will be the good way.

Comment: becase the return value of  `=> Number(item)` go nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not assigning it to the source array or not replacing the array with the new one that has all elements of the `number` type

You can also make it short as

```
arr.map(Number)
```

**1)** Assigining the converted number(from string to number type) back to source array index

```js
const arr = ["1", "2", "5", "7"];
arr.forEach((n, i, src) => (src[i] = Number(n)));
console.log(arr);
```

**2)** Assigning a new array that has all elements converted to type `number` back to `arr` variable.

```js
let arr = ["1", "2", "5", "7"];
arr = arr.map(n => Number(n));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Foreach does not return anything, so any update you want to save has to be done manually 
arr = ['1','200']; 
arr.forEach(item => Number(item));

console.log(arr);

// here you are updating the orinal array
arr = ['1','200']; 
arr.forEach((item, i ) => arr[i] = Number(item));

console.log(arr);

// here you are creating a new array without impacting the existing array
arr = ['1','200']; 
let newArr = arr.map((item) => Number(item));
console.log(arr);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: `arr.map(Number)` would also do the trick

Comment: I agree but i doubt  the person asking the question will understand anything

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything. It just mutates the array that it's given.

Its callback accepts three arguments. The first is the array *element*, the second is the *index* of that element, and the last is the array itself. We only have concern ourselves with the first two in this example.

Because `forEach` *mutates* the array you need to assign the the result of coercing the string to a number back to the array index.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

arr.forEach((item, i) => {
  arr[i] = Number(item);
});

console.log(arr);
```

The alternative is to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which creates a *new* array. We can use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) directly as the callback because it only accepts one argument which will be the array element.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

const newArr = arr.map(Number);

console.log(newArr);
```